# Different SWT browser IE versions during runtime

Tags: java, internet-explorer, swt

I want to create SWT IE browsers with different versions during program execution.
I know firstly we take IE version from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ Software \ Microsoft \ Internet Explorer \ Version. Then we look if there is a parameter HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Internet Explorer \ Main \ FeatureControl \ FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION \ java.exe (javaw.exe). If not, we create it with the above value.
How can I make SWT browser to take actual value from the registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Software \ Microsoft \ Internet Explorer \ Main \ FeatureControl \ FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION \ java.exe (I change it via jna). If I changed the value in the registry during runtime, SWT doesn't swap it.

And I don't understand how SWT understands that it need to emulate the version from the registry.

I'm using jdk 1.6, windows 7 x64, IE 11, SWT 4.3.

Comment: Now for me the only way is to restart the application:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp myJar-with-dependencies.jar MainClass ".concat(argument));
But I think it's not a good idea.